# Getting ObjectDisposedException in null-check

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.x and one entity looks like this (somewhat simplified):

```
public partial class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> XmlFormatID { get; set; }
    public virtual XmlFormat XmlFormat { get; set; }
}
```

And I use it like this, but in actual code it's in different methods:

```
Record record = null;
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    record = context.Records.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}

// Now the context is (correctly) disposed.
if (record.XmlFormatID.HasValue && record.XmlFormat != null)
{
    // It crashes before in this if.
}
```

The code above generates this exception:

> record.XmlFormat = 'record.XmlFormat' threw an exception of type
>   'System.ObjectDisposedException'

I do know that the error is caused because I try to lazy-load an entity when the context is disposed. I also know that I can simply change the code to `context.Records.Include(x => x.XmlFormat)`, or do the if-case when the context is opened.

The thing is that this line is re-used on different places in the application.

```
if (record.XmlFormatID.HasValue && record.XmlFormat != null)
{
    // It crashes in this if.
}
```

Sometimes within the context, sometimes when I've used include, and sometimes when it's not included. So my question is:

**How can I do the null-check and also take into account that it should work when the context is disposed?** I *do not* have access to `DbContext` when I do the null-check.

I have 3 scenarios:

1. `record.XmlFormat` is eager-loaded. Then I want to use the eager-loaded `XmlFormat`.
2. `record.XmlFormat` is not eager-loaded, but the context is open. Then I want to lazy-load it.
3. `record.XmlFormat` is not eager-loaded and the context is disposed. Then I simply don't want to enter the `if` and treat `XmlFormat` as `null`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot do it. But you can try three options below:

### First option.

As a *workaround*, I suggest you to turn off `LazyLoading` and get data using `EagerLoading` when you need it (as you already know). You can do it globally in the constructor of your context:

```
public MyContext : base("Name=MyContext")
{
    // Turn off lazy loading and proxy creation
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Or, if you want to use lazy loading at another parts of your application, you can do it while loading `Record`:

```
Record record = null;
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    // Turn of lazy loading and proxy creation. 
    // Disabling one of these also should be enough.
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    // Load record
    record = context.Records.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}

// Check for null
if (record.XmlFormatID.HasValue && record.XmlFormat != null)
{
}
```

If you do not want to write *lazy loading disabling code* repeatedly, you can add constructor which handles it:

```
public MyContext(bool enableLazyLoading) 
    : this()
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = enableLazyLoading;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = enableLazyLoading;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
using(var context = new DbContext(false))
{
    record = context.Records.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

### Second option.

If you can have access to context, you can check if it has been disposed or not, by checking `Database.Connection`. Add this method to your context:

```
public bool IsDisposed()
{
    bool isDisposed = false;
    try
    {
        isDisposed = Database.Connection != null;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        isDisposed = true;
    }
    return isDisposed;
}
```

Then add checks to your `if` condition:

```
Record record = null;
Context context = null; 
using(context = new DbContext())
{
    record = context.Records.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}

// Check
if (context != null
        && !context.IsDisposed()
        && record.XmlFormatID.HasValue 
        && record.XmlFormat != null)
{
}
```

### Third option

Last, but not least, you can always handle `ObjectDisposedException`. Add this method into your `Record` model:

```
class Record
{
    ...

    public bool IsXmlRootLoaded
    {
        bool isLoaded = false;
        try
        {
            isLoaded = XmlFormatID.HasValue && XmlFormat != null;
        }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            isLoaded = false;
        }
        return isLoaded;
    }
}
```

Then check if `XmlFormat` has been loaded:

```
if(record.IsXmlRootLoaded())
{
    // Do what you want.
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's not a bad idéa. But then I need to re-write a lot of code where I fetch Record, when all I really want is to check if the context i disposed or not.

Comment: Thank you. But the if-check would fail if the context is disposed, but `XmlFormat` was eager-loaded.

Comment: @smoksnes, you are right, haven't taken that into account. But, I would to stick to one, for example *XmlFormat should never be loaded using LazyLoading*, or *XmlFormat should never be loaded using eager loading*. May be it does not meet your needs, but it is what comes into my mind ).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It gives me something to think about, even though it doesn't fully solve my problem.

Comment: I understand @smoksnes . And of course, you can always handle `ObjectDisposedException` :)

Comment: @smoksnes, I have updated my answer once again. I think *Third option* must be the *First option*